# Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow - Policy to restrict user access to specific DAG?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, workflow, mwaa

I am trying to use Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow.
I see that only authorized IAM users can log into your Airflow UI because of integration with IAM. 
Is there any way to restrict the access of the user to a specific DAG within the Airflow(MWAA)? If yes, how to write the IAM policy for this?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible I guess. You'd first have to create DAG level roles within MWAA, see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html#dag-level-role . Then make sure your IAM user is assigned the right role in MWAA. There is a way to provide some kind of role mappings (IAM role -> MWAA role). Is this what you are looking for?